# emmip error from emmeans package - unevaluated constants

Tags: r, emmeans

Only today I learned about the `emmeans` package for R. I'm making a model similar to to the rdocumentation for the `emmip()` function, but I seem to get an error of some sort when I run my own data through it. The primary difference I spot between my data and the example model in the documentation is I'm using `cbind()` for my binomial model. Perhaps that's the primary culprit?

I'm unsure of what the error means, and I haven't currently found any other mentions of these errors out there, nor do I see clarification in the help section/manual. Is there any advice as to what's wrong with my data, or maybe what the error means?

```
#dput of data
test<-structure(list(Mean = c(33, 91.5, 7, 68, 25.75, 101, 2, 47.75, 
                              26, 125, 6.75, 51.5), Factor1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                          2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1400", "800"), class = "factor"), 
                     Factor2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("25", "31"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                  -12L), class = "data.frame")

#Creating a binomial generalized linear model of the above data
Mod_test<-glm(cbind(Mean*4, (800-(Mean*4)))  ~
                Factor1 * #Interactive effect of the factors
                Factor2,
              family = "binomial",
              data = test)

anova(Mod_test, test = "Chisq") #Confirming the factors are significant in their interaction

library(emmeans)
# On link scale: # This does create a plot, but produces an error
emmip(Mod_test, Factor1 ~ Factor2)

# On response scale: #This does not produce a plot, produces an additional error. 
emmip(Mod_test, Factor1 ~ Factor2, type = "response")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command does not produce an error, but a warning: *"There are unevaluated constants in the response formula. Auto-detection of the response transformation may be incorrect."* This is referring to this part of your model:

```
cbind(Mean*4, (800-(Mean*4)))
```

`emmeans` is not built to deal with this on the fly calculation of parameters. Just do the calculations beforehand:

```
test2 <- test
test2$Mean <- test2$Mean * 4
test2$Mean2 <- 800 - test2$Mean
Mod_test2 <- glm(
  cbind(Mean, Mean2) ~ Factor1 * Factor2,
  family = "binomial",
  data = test2
)

anova(Mod_test2, test = "Chisq")
emmip(Mod_test2, Factor1 ~ Factor2)
emmip(Mod_test2, Factor1 ~ Factor2, type = "response")
```

Now it all works fine.

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir! Yes, I can see your point about error/warning. Admittedly In my mind I think of them as one in the same, though obviously they are not! I appreciate your time!